# Better way to share data between components Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am using Angular 8. When I want to share variables between components by routing I do the following:

1. I add the data by `state` like: `this.router.navigate(["thing/"],{state: {data: {..}}})`
2. In the component I use `history.state.data`to get the variable.

It works but I was just wondering if there is a more optimus way to share data between components since I am getting the data from the browser’s history and if I refresh there is no data anymore

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more ways to pass data when routing. But due to the nature of WebApps, all in-memory data is lost when you reload the page (as this basically restarts your application). So if you want your data to persist, you have put it into a persistent storage. Now there are multiple options as well, like `SessionStorage`, `LocalStorage`, `ÌndexedDB` or even a WebServer. Which one is the most optimal solution for your case depends heavily on what kind of data you want to persist.

Additionally, there are options like Query Parameters and Path Parameters, that become part of the URL, so they basically persist through a refresh as well. But this also implicates that, if a user were to share the URL, he would share the data as well. If this is desired behaviour depends on your application.